# Random sale ad in Calendar

Tags: calendar, virus

This morning when I opened by computer, I saw a notification for an event that I never created.

[image]

I have not linked my email address on macbook and I'm not even from US. So why is there an event with some random website in my calendar? I checked which apps have access to calendar, and it came up empty. So is it just some harmless ad pushed by Apple or something malicious?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the event is unnerving but, thankfully, it is unlikely to be a virus or current problem with your MacBook.

Instead it is possible this event came from an unwanted e-mail; Mail.app on macOS and on iOS has the ability to add events discovered in your e-mails.

You can disable this feature using the steps from [How to disable suggested events in Calendar on iOS and Mac](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/11/16/how-to-disable-suggested-calendar-events-ios-mac-el-capitan/):

> ### How to disable Mail event suggestions on OS X
>
> Do the following on your Mac with OS X 10.11 El Capitan or later:
>
> 1. Launch Mail.
> 2. Choose Preferences from the Mail menu.
> 3. Click the General tab.
> 4. Select Never in the drop-down menu labeled “Add invitations to Calendar”.

Comment: can we just flag all these as dupes. We're seeing half a dozen a day right now

Comment: Of course, this is the first time I have seen this problem.